# Non-English character handling in html → JavaScript → Python 2.7

Tags: javascript, utf-8, aws-lambda, python-unicode

Problem:I am not able to receive non-English characters properly in the Python code in a web application. This web application is using the AWS API gateway and lambda at the server side.

#### Scenario

The user writes non-English characters (for example, 翻訳する) in the HTML element textarea. Which is received by the JavaScript code. And this value is transformed using encodeURIComponent($('#postText').val()) and sent in data part of a post call to the server using Ajax. Header contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' is sent in the HTTP post method call. FYI, the HTML page which contains this textarea element has <meta charset="utf-8">.

On the server I am running Python code in the Python 2.7 runtime. The received text is first unquoted using urllib.unquote(text) and then I try to print(text). It outputs the text in a garbled format (eg ç¿»è¨³ãã). Then I also try to `print(urllib.unquote(text).decode("utf-8"))` which again prints the same garbled characters.

For troubleshooting I have changed the encoding to UTF-16 in the post call header contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-16' and on Python I used `print(urllib.unquote(text).decode("utf-16"))` which prints something similar to what the user entered in the textarea, but it contains some garbled characters in between (for example, ꟃ뿂믂ꣃꣂ돂ꏃ臂駂ꏃ苂诂).

Is there a solution to handle non-English chars?

Comment: Can you try it in Python 3? Unicode is so much easier in Python 3.

Comment: i will try but what is the issue here.